# Creating a Rounded button with GWT

Tags: gwt

I have followed the instructions on this post 
[ImageButton in gwt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1193249/imagebutton-in-gwt)
to create my own Rounded button and it looks sort of ok visually.
What I want to do now is add click handlers for this new Class.  How can I go about this?  Do I need a click handler for both images, and the label?  What must I do then to configure this component using CSS?

Here is my code so far.

```java
    public class RoundButton extends Composite
    {
        protected final Label textHolder = new Label("helasdfasdf");
        protected final Image leftSide = new Image( "/icons/left.ico" );
        protected final Image rightSide = new Image( "/icons/right.ico" );
        protected final HorizontalPanel contentTable;

        public RoundButton()
        {
            contentTable = new HorizontalPanel();
            initWidget( contentTable );
            contentTable.add(leftSide);
            contentTable.add(textHolder);
            contentTable.add(rightSide);
        }

        public void setText( String text )
        {
            textHolder.setText(text);
        }   
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make your RoundButton more standartized I would implement the `com.google.gwt.event.dom.client.HasClickHandlers` interface and add the click event to whole your component (i.e. wrapper widget):

```java
public class RoundButton extends Composite implemens HasClickHandlers
{
    protected final Label textHolder = new Label("helasdfasdf");
    protected final Image leftSide = new Image( "/icons/left.ico" );
    protected final Image rightSide = new Image( "/icons/right.ico" );
    protected final HorizontalPanel contentTable;

    public RoundButton()
    {
        contentTable = new HorizontalPanel();
        initWidget( contentTable );
        contentTable.add(leftSide);
        contentTable.add(textHolder);
        contentTable.add(rightSide);
    }

    public void setText( String text )
    {
        textHolder.setText(text);
    }   


    public HandlerRegistration addClickHandler(ClickHandler handler)
    {
        return addDomHandler(handler, ClickEvent.getType());         
    }  

}
```

Comment: Cheers,  and how can I make this configurable using CSS.  I tried having a public setMyHeight( int height ) which would set the height of each subcomponent and then tried to see if doing .round{ myHeight: 10; }  in CSS would do anything but it didn't work.  Am I trying to do something that does not make sense?

Comment: Indeed, your are going not a right way with css. Gwt almost does not add any additional properties to css stylesheets (except sprites and contansts), so with css you should rely solely to css standards. So basically if you do not develop a library, you may have a single css stylesheet for your project where you define all your styles. In widgets you apply them using `setStyleName` method.

Comment: So just to be clear that I understand the best/correct way to apply styles to my new Class is to apply styles to the individual components that make it up?

Comment: @MayoMan generally speaking, yes. You define the styles which are necessary for your app style, and apply them to necessary parts.

Answer (score 0):

You can catch the clicks on the composite like this:

```java
public RoundButton()
{
    ...
    sinkEvents(Event.ONCLICK);
}

@Override
public void onBrowserEvent(Event event)
{
    super.onBrowserEvent(event);
    if (DOM.eventGetType(event) == Event.ONCLICK)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```